# How to manage a SMS conversation with Twilio?

Tags: php, twilio

I know how to send and receive SMS in Twilio.  What I don't know is how to build a PHP server application to send an SMS message with a question and, in case a SMS response for that question is not received in a specified amount of time (2 minutes or other value), would send a SMS reminder and restart the timer.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Will you please tell me how you are receiving text sms on twilio number?
I know how to send the text sms from twilio number to another number but unable to receive text sms on twilio number. Regards,
Nazrul

Comment: @Nazrul start here: http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/hello-monkey If that doesn't help, feel free to ask a new question here on SO or email our support team at help@twilio.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you want to do something on a schedule, you need to use a scheduler of some sort.  PHP does not have one built in (like the [Ruby delayed_job gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/delayed_job)), so you'd need to write a cron job or use something like [Moment](http://www.momentapp.com/).

The workflow would go something like this:

- Send the initial message using the Twilio [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest)
- Log that the message was sent in your app's data store with a timestamp for the time it was sent
- When a response is received, mark the log entry as completed
- Use the scheduler to run a process every minute or so looking for unanswered messages
- If your scheduled process finds a message that has 'expired', mark it as expired and re-send the message with a new log entry.

Comment: Thanks, John!  I was wondering if there was another way -- a Twilio-way -- of avoiding the cron job... :)

Comment: I've used beanstalkd (and pheanstalk) to accomplish similar things. In that case you're just running the message queue locally.